# Is there any command like "if strategy.open_orders > 0"?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Just as there is "strategy.position_size > 0", is there also a command that describes if there is an open order? For example, I place an entry with:

`if strategy.position_size==0 if close < ta.ema(close, 20) strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, stop= high)`

The next candlestick can surpass the maximum and enter, or after a few candles ahead, one appears that exceeds the maximum and activates the order.

If I want to determine that something is done only after entering "LONG" I write:

"if strategy.positon_size > 0
..."

But if I want to describe that a variable has a new value after activating the order "strategy.entry("LONG"..."), is there any command like "if strategy.open_orders > 0"?

Comment: what do you mean in phrase "activates the order"? is this when stop order will be placed or executed? it will be placed immediatelly after `strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, stop= high)` call; when it will have been executed, the `strategy.positon_size > 0` will be true.

Comment: The phrase "activates the order" I refer to it being placed, not executed. In this case I determine a condition like the one mentioned above and then I want to declare that after the order is placed, my exit target will be at 2x the size of the activation candle, not the entry one, because the entry will be the one that breaks the maximum and the target I want in relation to the candle of placement. If I write an `if strategy.positon_size > 0`, the calculation will be based on the execution candle. I need a command that specifically determines the candle that placed the order.

Comment: If I put the same command that performed the order placement, the `if close < ta.ema(close, 20)`, it calculates correctly based on the placement candle. However, if before reaching my target, another candle meets the `if close < ta.ema(close, 20)` condition, the target and the stop will be based on this new one and not on the order placement candle.

Comment: You can add additional condition: `if close < ta.ema(close, 20) and strategy.positon_size == 0`

Comment: Oh! Thanks Andrey, it was so simple and i couldn't figure it out. Now it works!